# How can I save a multiwindow perspective layout in Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

When I debug code in Eclipse, I like to take advantage of multiple monitors. In Eclipse Kepler, I did this by docking a couple of windows on my secondary monitor and then saving that perspective. In Eclipse Mars, whenever I switch perspectives, it resizes and relocates the floating windows that should appear on my secondary monitor. How do I preserve size and location of views in a perspective in Eclipse Mars?

Comment: For me allocating windows to monitors is correctly restored, only whether or not a window was maximized gets forgotten during exit / start cycles. Could be platform specific? If you have enough details for reproducing, consider filing a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform and select component UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work correctly was to create the perspective I wanted, save the perspective, then right click the perspective icon and click "reset". Now it resizes right whenever I switch perspectives.

Answer (score 0):

You could drag your program down near the console.

Comment: The idea is to pin it in such a way to only have one icon present while its running. Dragging and pinning will result in two icons. One for eclipse.exe and one for the running javaw.exe.